# How to check and recheck within ajax and wait until the value of the server message changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working ona application, when the user clicks on the "save" button in the application, it saves the information and restarts the server.
The form has to be successfully submitted before ajax success will fire. If the information is saved correctly from the form, i get a 200 success message from the server.

If there is success(200) the server restarts, when the Server restarts or is restarting it gives a 500 internal server message,  it take about 30 to 40 sec or more to restart the server so i have await time for 30 sec.. 
Once the server restarts it gives a 200 success server message.

Currently I am using  *Ajax call 2* to  check for success for data submission for server restart and the other 1st *Ajax call 1* to recheck the server is restarting and the data has been updated.

I have currently the following 2 ajax codes

Ajax call 1

```
 $.ajax({
           // dataType : 'jsonp',
            //jsonp : 'js',
            url: "some.json",
            beforeSend : function(jqXHR, settings) {
                console.info('in beforeSend');
                console.log(jqXHR, settings);
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(" 500 top data still loading"+ jqXHR +  " : " + textStatus +  " : " + errorThrown);
                console.info('in error');
                console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            },
            complete : function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
             alert(" complete "+ jqXHR +  " : " + textStatus);
                console.info('in complete');
                console.log(jqXHR, textStatus);
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            alert(" success "+ jqXHR +  " : " + textStatus);
                console.info('in success');
                console.log(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            }
        });
```

Ajax call 2

```
 $(function () {
    $("#save").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "some.json",
            data: json_data,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log(arguments);
                console.log(xhr.status);
                alert("Your changes are being submitted: " + textStatus + " : " + xhr.status);
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                /*                   
        This gives a messagthat  the server is restarting iina modal window and waits for 30sec
        */
                $('#myModal-loading').modal('show');

/***  Re check bit by Ryan ***/
var restartCheck = window.setInterval(
$.ajax({
    // dataType : 'jsonp',
    //jsonp : 'js',
    url: "../../../../../rest/configuration",
    beforeSend: function (jqXHR, settings) {
        console.info('in beforeSend');
        console.log(jqXHR, settings);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(" 500 top data still loading " + jqXHR + " : " + textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
        console.info('in error');
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);

    },
    complete: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert(" complete " + jqXHR + " : " + textStatus);
        console.info('in complete');
        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus);
    },
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        window.clearInterval(restartCheck);
        alert(" success " + jqXHR + " : " + textStatus);
        console.info('in success');
        console.log(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
    }
}), 30000); //This will call the ajax function every 3 seconds until the clearInterval function is called in the success callback.
/*** recheck bit **/

                setTimeout(function () {
                    location.reload(true);
                }, 30000);

                $('<div id="loading">Loading...</div>').insertBefore('#myform-wiz');

            },

            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText + " - " + errorThrown + " : " + jqXHR.status);

            }
        });

    });
});



});
```

Is it possible to re-check continuously within success in `Ajax call 2` , if the server is giving a 500 error message to check for restart of server and recheck for success for 200 before  redirecting back to the updated page?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just use a setInterval. Don't forget to clear it in the success callback.

```
var restartCheck = window.setInterval(    
$.ajax({
           // dataType : 'jsonp',
            //jsonp : 'js',
            url: "some.json",
            beforeSend : function(jqXHR, settings) {
                console.info('in beforeSend');
                console.log(jqXHR, settings);
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(" 500 top data still loading"+ jqXHR +  " : " + textStatus +  " : " + errorThrown);
                console.info('in error');
                console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);

            },
            complete : function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert(" complete "+ jqXHR +  " : " + textStatus);
                console.info('in complete');
                console.log(jqXHR, textStatus);
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                window.clearInterval(restartCheck);
                alert(" success "+ jqXHR +  " : " + textStatus);
                console.info('in success');
                console.log(data, textStatus, jqXHR);
            }
        })
, 3000);  //This will call the ajax function every 3 seconds until the clearInterval function is called in the success callback.
```

Comment: Do I plug that within my 2nd ajax call on success or just keep them both separate as i have orginally and modify the first ajax call 1?

Comment: Either way.  I would probably wrap that up in its own function and call it from the success callback of your "Ajax 2" function, just to keep it clean.  Alternatively you could just embed the whole thing there but it would be tough to read.

Comment: I added your code  at succes of "AJAX 2" coudl you please check if that the right way? it didnt seem to wait i think for the old 200 to change to 500(restart) .,. The proces at initial success(200)-->(wait 30sec for(500)- or recheck -wait another 30 sec for 200-rechck. all these server response values have to checked and rechecked until it complete

Answer (score 0):

Well, my idea could be to put your `ajax` request inside a method and do the following:

---

**1.** Send the request to save your data and restart server.

**2.** In the process you need to validate that the data is not repeated in the database.

**3.** If there is an error present then the method is executed again and again but the data is not double saved due to the validation implemented in number 2 and only the server gets restarted.

---

To start all this, I made a simulation of your situation. Just to know, I don't know which kind of server language are you using (because it is not specified in the question `tags`) but I will use `PHP` for making this easy...

**The following example makes this:**

A user inputs his/her name inside a textbox and then when he/she clicks the "Save" button, the data will be send to the server and, after `50s` the callback will be returned to client side. But, if the input name is `oscar` then the server will return a `500 HTTP` error and you will see how the code gets executed again to try "restarting" the server one more time (remember it's a simulation). Otherwise everything will return a `200 HTTP` OK.

- Please read all comments inside the code, check the browser console and if you can... test it!

---

***index.php***: This is the main page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Simulation</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
     save();
  });
});

function save() {

    $('#msg').text('Please wait while restarting the server...').show();
    $('#btn').hide();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: $('form').serialize(),
        statusCode: {
            500: function() { 

                console.log('500 HTTP error present, try again...');

                /* Invoke your method again to try restarting the server. 
                 * To avoid double save of 'name' variable please 
                 * check the first comments at 'process.php' file.
                 */
                $('#msg').text('Re-trying to restart the server...');

                /* While waiting check the browser console and look that 
                 * the save method is getting invoked again and again until 
                 * you change the name from 'oscar' to another.
                 */
                save();
            },
            200: function() {
                $('#msg').text('Server restarted!').fadeOut('slow');
                $('#btn').fadeIn();
            }
        }
    });

};
</script>
<body>
<span id="msg"></span>
<br/>
<form>
Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/><br/>
<input type="button" name="btn" id="btn" value="Save"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

***process.php***: This file will receive the `ajax` request from jQuery (Just to know I am using version **1.7.2**).

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])){

  $name = $_POST['name'];

  /* TODO: In this case and at this point, you need to save the 
   * name into DB but only if it doesn't exist because if 500 error
   * is present, then the request have to be validated again to 
   * just restart the server (maybe doing some if/else to evaluate) and 
   * don't make a double save.
   */

  /* TODO: restart the server... 
   * I will simulate the long wait for the server to respond (50s)
   * using sleep before sending back the name variable to client side.
   *
   * But!
   * I will do a tricky thing at this point. If the name is 'oscar' then
   * I will produce a 500 HTTP error to see what happens at client side...
   */

   /* Wait first 27s */
   sleep(27);

   /* If $name is 'oscar' then return 500 error */
   if($name == 'oscar') {
    throw new Exception('This is a generated 500 HTTP server error.');
   }

   /* If $name != 'oscar' then wait 23s to simulate 
    * the long time for restarting server...
    */
    sleep(23);

    flush();

    /* Retun $name in the callback */
    echo $name;  
}
?>
```

---

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: How would you go about rechecking the restart() periodically, if it has finally changed to 200 from 500, keep in mind it take about 40 to 50sec for teh server restart? Also, the restart is a 2 step process ,first is 200 for succesfull form submission and during server restart is 500 and once the server is done restarting and values updated it changes to 200. there is 30 to 40 sec wait time for each of those steps.

Comment: Also, how do you redirect to the 'statusCode' from complete? -thanks

Comment: @user244394 Please check my updated post and will be good if you can tell me which language are you using at server side.

Comment: The backend is just giving the json file , which is generated by java. But we donot need to worry about the backend since based on form submission . I am getting various server responses back 200--500 -200 etc , so my client side code needs to process the various ajax responses . once the form is submitted and processed correctly, the JSOn get updated in the backend and when the response is 200 I display the updated json values ina form.

Comment: The backend is just giving the json file , which is generated by java.Once the form is successfully submited, i pass the jsondata back to backnd.We donot need to worry about the backedn code, I need to handle the various ajax responses and the lags between the responses.As in my code above, once the form has been submitted successfully, the response is 200 (there is some wait for 200 due to server lag)and then we need wait for ajax response of 500 which means server is restarting and could take 30 to 50 sec before it changes to 200 again after restart.Then i redirect back to the updated page

Comment: I have posted my javascript in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dev1212/ABLdJ/2/  I got most of it to work, but after server has changed from 500 to 200, it seems to keep looping inside the restart function.